# How to use the useRef hook for setNativeProps in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert the class component of React Native to a functional component that involves `useRef`.  Following is the class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";

import { interpolateNumber, interpolateRgb } from "d3-interpolate";

export default class animations extends Component {
  state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(0)
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const positionInterpolate = interpolateNumber(0, 200);
    const colorInterpolate = interpolateRgb("rgb(255,99,71)", "rgb(99,71,255)");;

    this.state.animation.addListener(({value}) => {
      const position = positionInterpolate(value);
      const color = colorInterpolate(value);

      const style = [
        styles.box,
        {
          backgroundColor: color,
          transform: [
            {translateY: position}
          ]
        }
      ];
      this._view.setNativeProps({ style });
    });
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handlePress}>
          <View style={styles.box} ref={view => this._view = view} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

When I convert to the following functional component, I get the following error:

> TypeError that someRef.setNativeProps is not a function. (In
>   'someRef.setNativeProps({   style: style })', 'someRef.setNativeProps'
>   is undefined)

```
import 
    React, 
    { 
        useState, 
        useEffect,
        useRef
    } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Animated,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'
import {
    interpolateNumber,
    interpolateRgb, 
} from 'd3-interpolate'

export default d3number = () => {
    const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(1))
    const [position, setPosition] = useState()
    const someRef = useRef(null)
    const startAnimation = () => {
        Animated.timing(animation, {
            toValue: 2,
            duration: 1500,
        }).start()
    }

    const positionInterpolate = interpolateNumber(0, 300)
    useEffect(() => {
        animation.addListener(({value}) => {
            const pos = positionInterpolate(value)
            setPosition(pos)
        })
        const style = [
            styles.box, 
            {
                transform: [
                    {
                        translateY: position
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        someRef.setNativeProps({ style })
        // console.log(someRef.setNativeProps)
    }, [])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={startAnimation}>
                <View 
                    style={styles.box}
                    ref={someRef}
                />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Update: this was resolved by including the style within the listener

```
        if (!someRef.current) {
            return;
        }
        animation.addListener(({value}) => {
            const style = [
                styles.box, 
                {
                    transform: [
                        {
                            translateY: positionInterpolate(value)
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            someRef.current.setNativeProps({ style })            
        })

        // console.log(someRef.setNativeProps)
    }, [someRef.current])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the docs [1] The value of the ref is kept at `ref.current`. So you need to run `someRef.current.setNativeProps`.

That said your `useEffect` code will have problems because `someRef` will be set to `null` on your first render when `useEffect` is running. You'll have to add `someRef.current` to the `useEffect` dependencies array so the effect is called whenever `someRef` updates and add a condition to not call `someRef.current.setNativeProps` when `someRef.current` is `null`. You may want to skip the entire `useEffect` body unless `someRef.current` is not `null`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!someRef.current) {
          return;
        }
        animation.addListener(({value}) => {
            const pos = positionInterpolate(value)
            setPosition(pos)
        })
        const style = [
            styles.box, 
            {
                transform: [
                    {
                        translateY: position
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        someRef.current.setNativeProps({ style })
    }, [someRef.current]) # note the addition of `someRef.current` here so the effect runs again when the ref is set
```

[1] https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref